# Tenth arrives during or after the silent shemonei esreh - sources

Tags: halacha, tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, minyan, tefillah-betzibbur

What responsa are there on whether to have chazaras hashatz when the tenth arrives (completing the minyan) during or even after the tefillah b'lachash (silent prayer)?

Comment: Hi DrM, welcome! I don't have my notes together to give a clear answer now, but I would recommend seeing Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim 69 regarding Pores Al Shema and Over Lifnei HaTeivah. You may find more sources around there.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) DrM and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 6):

I don't know about responsa, but it's an entire Siman in Shulchan Aruch - and it's called Pores Al Shma - *[Orach Chaim 69 - דין פורס על שמע](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.69.1?lang=bi)*.

In short: Once the tenth man arrives, one says Kadish, Borchu, (the bracha of Yotzer according to the Mechaber, but not the Remo) and then Chazarat Hashatz.

In the original:

> אם יש בני אדם **שהתפללו כל אחד בפ"ע ביחיד** ולא שמעו לא קדיש ולא קדושה **עומד אחד מהם ואומר קדיש וברכו וברכה ראשונה יוצר אור** ולא יותר וזה נקרא **פורס על שמע** לשון חתיכה פרוסה שאין אומרים אלא קצת ממנה:‏
>
> ***הגה** ועכשיו לא נהגו לומר כל ברכת יוצר אור אלא אומרים **קדיש וברכו** והם עונים אחריו ברוך ה' וכו'. י"א שפורסין בק"ש של ערבית כמו בשחרית [כל בו וב"י בשם הר"ן] ולא נהגו כן משום דליכא קדיש קודם ברכו של ערבית.‏*
>
> ולאחר שסיימו ברכ' יוצר אור **אומר אבות וגבורות וקדושה ואתה קדוש** וזה נקרא עובר לפני התיבה ואין עושין דברים אלו בפחות מי' משום דהוי דברים שבקדוש' וצריך לחזור אחר ששה שלא שמעו דהיינו רוב העשרה ואם אינם נמצאים אפילו בשביל אחד שלא שמע אומרים ואפי' מי ששמע יכול לפרוס על שמע ולעבור לפני התיבה בשביל אותו שלא שמע ומ"מ אם אותו שלא שמע בקי לפרוס על שמע ולעבור לפני התיבה מוטב שיפרוס ויעבו' לפני התיב' הוא משיפרוס ויעבור לפני התיבה אחר שכבר שמע:‏
>
> ***הגה** ומי שעובר לפני התיבה ואמר ג' ברכות הראשונות **ישלים כל התפלה** ולא יפסיק אע"פ שכבר התפלל אבל האחרים יכולין להפסיק אח"כ וכ"ש שאם לא התפלל הפורס והעובר לפני התיבה תחלה שישלים תפלתו אע"פ שיצטרך לקרא אח"כ ק"ש ולא יסמוך גאולה לתפלה [ב"י בשם מהרי"א] ואסור להפסיק בדברים אלו בין גאולה לתפלה או בק"ש וברכותיה ולכן אסור לש"צ להפסיק בין ק"ש לתפלה או בק"ש וברכותיה כדי לפרוס על שמע לאותן הבאים לב"ה לאחר שהתפללו הקהל קדיש וברכו והתחיל בברכת יוצר אור אבל בברכת ערבית שהוא רשות יכול להפסיק להוציא אחרים י"ח ומ"מ איש אחר יכול לפרוס על שמע או להתפלל בי' כל התפילה אפי' באותו ב"ה שכבר התפללו להוציא אחרים י"ח רק שלא יעמוד החזן השני במקום שעמד הראשון דזהו נראה גנאי לראשונים דהוי כאלו לא יצאו בראשונה י"ח [תשובת מהר"י מינץ סי' ט"ו] ונ"ל דוקא שעדיין הראשונים בב"ה אלא שהשלימו סדרם אבל אם יצאו הראשונים יוכל לעמוד החזן אף במקום שעמד הראשון:‏*