# What are the halachic issues when the 10th man arrives after the first 9 have already completed the Amida?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, minyan

For example, this morning I was one of the first nine men at Shacharis. After we completed the silent Amida we waited for a tenth to arrive. We then repeated the Amida and proceeded with Tachanun etc. This is the situation contemplated [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/97600/tenth-arrives-during-or-after-the-silent-shemonei-esreh-sources).

This waiting during Shacharis is sometimes tense. Some of the people present may hope to finish the service quickly and arrive at work on time.

Are there any valid halachic ways of avoiding this issue? - for example, to proceed with the service without waiting, and then to repeat the Amida later, should a tenth man eventually appear.